# C++ : Factorize code without passing a million arguments

Tags: c++, refactoring

I am doing C/C++ programming (mostly C++) and I find myself in need to factorize code that is really twice the same, except every occurence of "left" is replaced with "right". Once the code finishes, I need to know if it was the "left" or "right" version being executed, but that's all, both will return a number out of which I can make sense (once combined with the left or right information).

In this setup, every change needs to be done twice, and that's annoying.

So I could simply factorize by replacing left/right with "other" and call the factorized function twice, knowing each time if I am calling it for "left" or for "right".

Now as we reach that part of code, there are already a million variables (cursors, IDs, arrays being filled, etc ...). So if I wanted to factorize the left/right code, I'd need the function to have a gazillion arguments, and that'd look quite ugly.

I also don't want to overload my C++ class with attributes only used in this case.

Any suggestions to factorize smoothly here ?

```
    int arrayRight[many], arrayLeft[many], cursor;

    while(1)
    {
         rightThing = arrayRight[cursor];
         // Process with RightThing assigned
         // ...
         // ...
         // ...

        leftThing = arrayLeft[cursor]
         // Process with RightThing assigned
         // ...
         // ...
         // ...

        cursor++;
   }
```

Comment: You may group your arguments into struct/class and then pass only those instance.

Comment: Thought about that, but still a hassle to define a struct just for this once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this? (It only works on C++14 since it uses auto lambda)

```
auto func = [&](auto& theThing){
    // blah, blah code
};

func(arrayRight[cursor]);
func(arrayLeft [cursor]);
```

`[&]` here means import all variables in the same scope into the lambda function.

For older C++ version, I use the following code as a ugly way (in a school's project of C99).

```
int* pData[2] = {arrayRight, arrayLeft};
for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    int* theThing = pData[i];
    // blah, blah
}
```

Some of my friend told me macro can hold VA_ARGS so here is a macro way. It should work on GCC. But for MSVC 2003, it doesn't work though. (`__typeof` need to be replaced by `boost::typeof`, and anonymous struct definition is not supported in older version of MSVC)

```
#define in(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define PP_ARG_N( \
          _1,  _2,  _3,  _4,  _5,  _6,  _7,  _8,  _9, _10, \
         _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, _17, _18, _19, _20, \
         _21, _22, _23, _24, _25, _26, _27, _28, _29, _30, \
         _31, _32, _33, _34, _35, _36, _37, _38, _39, _40, \
         _41, _42, _43, _44, _45, _46, _47, _48, _49, _50, \
         _51, _52, _53, _54, _55, _56, _57, _58, _59, _60, \
         _61, _62, _63, N, ...) N
#define PP_RSEQ_N()                                        \
         63, 62, 61, 60,                                   \
         59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50,           \
         49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40,           \
         39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30,           \
         29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20,           \
         19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,           \
          9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0
#define PP_NARG_(...)    PP_ARG_N(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_NARG(...)     PP_NARG_(__VA_ARGS__, PP_RSEQ_N())

#define withInternal(dataType, desiredType, x, dataCnt, data...) for(struct {size_t __i; dataType __t[dataCnt];} __s = {0, data}; x = __s.__t[__s.__i], __s.__i < dataCnt; __s.__i++)
#define with(x, ...) withInternal(__typeof(__VA_ARGS__), __typeof(__VA_ARGS__), x, PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)
#define withConst(x, ...) withInternal(__typeof(__VA_ARGS__), __typeof((__VA_ARGS__) + 0), x, PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)
#define withType(tn, x, ...) withInternal(tn, tn, x, PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)
```

and when you use it:

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    int s1=2, s2=3;
    with(x, in(s1, s2))
        cout<<x<<endl;
    withConst(x, in(45, 55))
        cout<<x<<endl;
    withType(int, x, in(45, s1, 55, s2))
        cout<<x<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I believe it is more clear.

- `with` works with variables (basically) because when passing consts to `with`, gcc `__typeof` generate an automated const type for `x` which could not be assigned.
- `withConst` uses a `x+0` trick to remove the const type of variables but `+` operator doesn't work on every datatype so it has limitations.
- `withType` specifies a data type, it is suitable for mixed situation.

Comment: Looks like `arrayRight` and `arrayLeft` are `int` arrays, so you could just use `int&` to make it work in C++11.

Comment: We're currently discussing switching to C++2003, so no C++14 until some time ! But I like the idea though.

Comment: @TartanLlama Still have to pass those pointers ... There are a few more arrays than I described here ...

Comment: @C.THIN, here is a workaround for older C++ though it is ugly. LOL

Comment: Ugly, but I like it.

Comment: @C.THIN I added another macro wrapper for the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try batching things together like this:

```
while(1)
{
    vector<int> things;

    int rightThing = arrayRight[cursor];
    things.push_back(rightThing);

    int leftThing = arrayLeft[cursor];
    things.push_back(leftThing);

    for(vector<int>::iterator thing = things.begin(); thing != things.end(); ++thing)
    {
        // Process Thing
        // ...
        // ...
        // ...
    }

    cursor++;
}
```